# C++ termination error 'std::bad_alloc'

Tags: c++, memory, vector

I am getting the following error when I run my program for a lot of iterations:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
```

I have read and found that this is a memory related issue. I am using 2d vectors to store data and do some processing. I use `&vector_name` whenever I pass a vector to another function, and cannot determine what is going on.

Should I use `vector_name.clear();` after each iteration of the processing? I am doing it 1000 + times so would this help at all? Any other pointers as to what I could check would be much appreciated.

The exception throws at the end of the for loop.

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 10000; i++){
    init_increasing_list = std::vector<int>(adj_list[vertex].begin() + 1, adj_list[vertex].end());
    candidate = MaxClique(initial_vertex, initial_increasing_list, adj_list);
    if (candidate.size() > max_size){
        max = candidate;
        max_size = max.size();
        std::cout << max_size << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << "Loop ended" << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: More of your code is probably need to be shown.

Comment: You should probably check that `adj_list[vertex]` has at least two elements.

Comment: BTW: having both "adj_list" and "adjacency_list" is an open invitation to a bug party.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting `std::bad_alloc`, it can mean one of two things:

#### 1. You're running out of memory

This could easily be caused by a memory leak; that is, allocating a memory dynamically and then losing the last pointer to it, so that it cannot be deallocated. You should check your program for those, using a tool such as valgrind.

If you're not leaking memory, check whether you're promptly freeing memory which you know you will no longer need. You cannot realistically post your whole program, so I cannot offer targeted advice, but in general, if your iterations are independent of each other, you should free all resources after an iteration has finished and before starting the next one. Etc.

#### 2. Your memory is too fragmented and there's no room for the big object you're currently trying to allocate.

This one is a tougher nut to crack, but it's fortunately also less likely to be the cause of your issues. If, however, you find your program is actually leak-free and not holding on to resources for longer than necessary, you will have to try attacking this possibility too.

For this, you'll have to think about your memory allocation patterns, modify them to avoid fragmentation. One possiblity would be to find out what sizes of objects you frequently allocate, and create dedicated memory pools for them. For example, allocate a sufficiently large buffer for your 48-byte objects and handle allocation/deallocation of them within this buffer yourself. To actually implement this, you should look into the `Allocator` template parameters of standard containers, overloading (de)allocation functions `operator new` and `operator delete`, and similar.